# Java replace all replacing one of every two occurrences

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have a strange behavior on a really simple problem.

I have a string with a lot of null strings:

> "a;b;c;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null"

Which I remove using this method:

```
public String replaceAllNull(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll(";null;", ";;");

    //if first item = null remove it
    if(s.startsWith("null;")) {
        s = s.substring(4,s.length());
    }

    //if last item = null remove it
    if(s.endsWith(";null")) {
        s = s.substring(0,s.length()-4);
    }
    return s;
}
```

It was working fine until my string became bigger and I saw this strange output

> "a;b;c;;null;;null;;null;;null;;"

It's only removing one occurrence out of two.

I think I can understand that during one replace program skips one ";" then the second null is not recognized by my regex ";null;". But I don't get why is this happening?

Comment: Split on `';'`, remove `"null"` strings, re-join with `';'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After one instance of `";null;"` is replaced by `";;"`, then both of the semicolons are already processed, so that the second `;` cannot be considered as the start of another replacement for the next `";null;"` occurrence.  The pattern cannot be matched again until after another "null" has been passed up, to reach the next semicolon.

What you can use is a pattern that doesn't attempt to match the semicolons, but it must check to see if they are there.  You can use [a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (find "lookahead" and "lookbehind" on the linked page).  Here, positive means that it verifies that the pattern of the lookbehind/lookahead exists, but doesn't match it.

The positive lookbehind is of the format `(?<=X)`, where `X` is the pattern to look behind the main pattern to see if it exists.  Also, the positive lookahead is of the format `(?=X)`, where `X` is the pattern to look ahead of the main pattern to see if it exists.

Here, we look for the beginning of the line `^` or a semicolon before the match, and the end of the line `$` or a semicolon after the match.  Then we simply replace the actual match, `"null"`, with an empty string.

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=^|;)null(?=$|;)", "");
```

Comment: this is working, I tested it in my junits test and it fulfill all the test cases, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Stream by splitting the String

```
return Stream.of(s.split(";", -1))
             .map(w -> "null".equals(w) ? "" : w)
             .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
```

Comment: Won't this have the same problem with empty strings surrounded by `';'`? Wouldn't a filter be more appropriate than a map?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca a filter removes the element so the number of ; would be less. Not sure what you mean by the first question. This will remove replace every `null` cell with an empty string.

Comment: I mean that the situation will be left as "a;b;c;;;;;;;;;;" because what `map` returns will have empty strings inside, which I'm not sure it's what OP wants: this may only be my impression but I think the desired result would be "a;b;c". That's why I suggested a filter.

Comment: the result wanted is "a;b;c;;;;;;;;;;" (in my case it's needed) I tested this answer it with different case and it's working !

Comment: @RedRaccoon you can accept an answer by clicking the tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution, use this instead of the above big code

```
public String replaceAllNull(String s) {
    return s.replace("null" , "");
}
```

> Example

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    String str = "a;r;c;e;null;d;f;e;null;s;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;s;";
    System.out.println(String.format("Before replacing null %s", str));
    str = replaceAllNull(str);
    System.out.println(String.format("After replacing null %s", str));
}
```

> Output

```
Before replacing null a;r;c;e;null;d;f;e;null;s;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;s;
After replacing null a;r;c;e;;d;f;e;;s;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;s;
```

> **Update** to avoid such words that contains null in it, an alternate is here

```
public static String replaceAllNull(String s) {
    String[] arr = s.split(";");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
            arr[i] = "";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sb.append(arr[i]);
        if (i < arr.length - 1)
            sb.append(";");
    }
    if (s.endsWith(";"))
        sb.append(";");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This would also alter an cell with null in it but might be a reasonable assumption. e.g. disannulled nulliparous nullifiers nullifying nulliparae nulliparas nullipores annulling nullified nullifier nullifies nullipara nullipore nullities annulled nullahs nullify nulling nullity nullah nulled nulls